# Compare String to Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the procedure below where I want to convert string data into date and compare it with other dates.

The `eev.screen_entry_value` is a Varchar2 with values in the format "2018/10/26 00:00:00".

I want to convert this to date format and compare with other dates as below-

```
TO_DATE(to_date(eev.screen_entry_value,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY') BETWEEN P_START_DATE AND P_END_DATE;
```

However, I'm getting an error-

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Below is my code snippet-

```
declare
 p_start_date DATE;
 p_end_date DATE;
 p_screen_entry_value varchar2(60);
BEGIN
 SELECT ptp2.start_date, ptp2.end_date
 into p_start_date, p_end_date
 FROM  per_time_periods ptp
 , per_time_periods ptp2
 , pay_payrolls_f pp
 WHERE pp.payroll_name LIKE 'US Semi-Monthly'
 AND TRUNC(sysdate) BETWEEN pp.effective_start_date AND pp.effective_end_date
 AND pp.payroll_id = ptp.payroll_id
 AND TRUNC(sysdate) BETWEEN ptp.START_DATE AND ptp.END_DATE
 AND ptp.payroll_id = ptp2.payroll_id
 AND ptp.end_date BETWEEN ptp2.start_date AND ptp2.end_date;
 dbms_output.put_line(p_start_date);
 dbms_output.put_line(p_end_date);

 SELECT eev.screen_entry_value
 into p_screen_entry_value
 FROM  pay_input_values_f piv,
 pay_element_types_f et,
 pay_element_links_f el,
 pay_element_entries_f ee, 
 pay_element_entry_values_f eev
 WHERE  
  ee.assignment_id IN (364018)
  AND ee.element_link_id = el.element_link_id
  AND sysdate  BETWEEN el.effective_start_date 
            AND el.effective_end_date
  AND ee.element_type_id = et.element_type_id
  AND sysdate BETWEEN et.effective_start_date
            AND et.effective_end_date
  AND et.attribute_category = 'US Elements'
  AND et.attribute1 = 'Y' --Interface to ProBusiness
  AND ee.element_entry_id = eev.element_entry_id
  AND sysdate  BETWEEN eev.effective_start_date
            AND eev.effective_end_date
  AND eev.input_value_id = piv.input_value_id
  AND sysdate  BETWEEN piv.effective_start_date
            AND piv.effective_end_date
  AND eev.screen_entry_value IS NOT NULL  
  AND et.element_name IN ('HV Sign On Bonus','HV Retention  Bonus','Relocation')  --XX_HR_NONREC_ELEMENTS
  AND piv.name IN('Vested 1 Date');
 --AND TO_DATE(to_date(eev.screen_entry_value,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY') BETWEEN P_START_DATE AND P_END_DATE;
 dbms_output.put_line(p_screen_entry_value);

 end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing `to_date(to_date(...))` doesn't really make sense. The inner one converts the string to a date, then the outer one tries to convert that date to... a date. To try to do that it has to implicitly convert the date back to a string again, and it will use your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for that implicit step.

If you wanted to get it back to a string in a specific format you would use `to_char()` for the outer call:

```
to_char(to_date(eev.screen_entry_value,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY') ...
```

But the values you are comparing against are dates, so you don't need or want that second conversion at all:

```
to_date(eev.screen_entry_value,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
BETWEEN P_START_DATE AND P_END_DATE
```

Comment: I tried using both ways you suggested. For both, I get the error below. Please advise- ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at line 20
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

Comment: Are you sure all the string values are actually in that format? This is why you shouldn't be storing dates as strings in the first place, of course. (Assuming they really are strings...)

Comment: SCREEN_ENTRY_VALUE is a seeded column which is VARCHAR2(60)  in table pay_element_entry_values_f. From front-end we store mixed data types- Character, Numberic, Date, etc into this field. This is a seeded setup too for HR Element entry input values. I also tried- select screen_entry_value 
into l_screen_entry_value from (<query used above>) where to_date(screen_entry_value,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN P_START_DATE AND P_END_DATE;

Comment: In the method above, I'm trying to fetch only the date values from the inner query, and then doing the date comparison in the outer query. I'm still getting the same error- ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: But you aren't only fetching the date values. You're getting all strings representing anything and trying to convert them all to dates. The error is probably coming from a 'number' value. You could try to pattern-match first; or if you're on 12cR2 you can use the [default on error](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html) syntax, e.g. to  return null for whatever can't be converted.

Comment: We are on version- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit. I get error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis for the query below- SELECT TO_DATE('10/15/2018' DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) FROM   DUAL;

Comment: SELECT TO_DATE('15-OCT-2018' DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
FROM   DUAL;  also gives the error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: You're on 12cR1; like I said in my previous comment, that syntax is for 12cR2 (12.2.0.1) onwards.

Comment: I was able to workaround this issue by removing the to_date condition from the select statement and adding an IF-ELSE later on in the procedure. That worked. Thank you for your help though- IF (TO_DATE(l_screen_entry_value,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN P_START_DATE AND P_END_DATE) THEN
.....
      END IF;

Comment: I would still like to know how I can add the to_date condition in the SELECT statement itself, because fetching all the records in the cursor and later checking for a date range might lead to performance issues.